# replacement for cartodb.SQL({user: 'user'}).execute(sqlquery) in new cartojs

Tags: carto, carto-js

this used to be my code in older carto.js

```
cartodb.SQL({user: 'user'}).execute(sqlquery).done(function (data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

how to readapt it in newer cartojs 4.0 beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any HTTP client like [axios](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/sql/) (example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/838e40ad432f72f121563a6169298eea)) or just use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) if you are OK on the browsers that [support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) nowadays.

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer, you saved my day. I was really wondering where it went in the new JS.

Comment: Can we Commit Changes using axios ?

Comment: Again that's independant from the library, to commit changes to your data you need to pass your API key on the request so your call to the SQL API is authenticated. You don't want to do this in a public facing application of course since your API key enables full access to your account. On this [training material](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-workshop/blob/master/04-database/exercises/sql_stored_procedures.md#functions-with-security-definer) you have details on how to create a function that is accessible to the anonymous user but that also allows to make changes.